# I want to create quartiles in R for a specific value. I want to create the quartiles category-wise. How can I do that?

Tags: r, analytics, quartile

For Example: The average price of Category A and Category B is X & Y respectively. Both categories contain number of products. I want to create the quartile on the basis of average price for each category.

Comment: Please share some data, code and so on. Your question is very unclear and should be improved.

Comment: "I want to create the quartile on the basis of average price for each category." You can't deduce a quartile from the average.

Answer (score 0):

As Roland said in comment, you cannot deduce a quartile from the average.
Also your question is very unclear, I'm trying to answer it with the information I know.

[This post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/134229/finding-quartiles-in-r) goes in more depth about quantiles and how to find them.

The [`quantile` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/quantile.html) will print the values of each quartile.

```
> quantile(iris$Sepal.Length)
  0%  25%  50%  75% 100% 
 4.3  5.1  5.8  6.4  7.9
```

If let's say you want to get the first and third quartile you can do the following, `c(0.25, 0.75)` represents the quantile percentages you want. You could also do `quantile(data, probs=0.5)` to get the median(2nd quartile):

```
> Quart <- quantile(iris$Sepal.Length, probs= c(0.25, 0.75))
> Q1 <- Quart[1]
> Q2 <- Quart[2]
> Q1
  25% 
  5.1 
> Q2
  75% 
  6.4
```

Hope this helps you!